# Google App Maker User Picker and how to return all values from the Directory model

Tags: google-app-maker

I am using the User Picker for Google App Maker and it only seems to return the email address.  Before using the User Picker, you need to add the Directory model into your app, which I have done already.

My question is, Is there a way to use that selected email as the key and grab the corresponding record in the Directory model?

I have some code which returns `undefined` for the 3 values (userFullname, userPhone, and userAddress) I am looking for.

Server Script Code:

```
function getUserInfoByEmail(email) {

    var userFullname;
    var userPhone;
    var userAddress;

    console.log("serverCode - getUserInfoByEmail: " + email);

    var query = app.models.Directory.newQuery();

    query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = email;
    var records = query.run();
    if (records === null) {
        console.log("serverCode - getUserByEmail() - records is null");
    }
    console.log("serverCode - getUserByEmail() - " + records.length);


    for (var user in records) {

        if (user === null) {
            console.log("serverCode - getUserByEmail() - user is null");
        }


        console.log("serverCode - getUserByEmail() - user: " + user);
        userFullname = user.FullName;
        userPhone = user.PrimaryPhone;
        userAddress = user.PrimaryAddress;

        console.log("serverCode - getUserInfoByEmail - userPhone: " + userPhone);
        console.log("serverCode - getUserInfoByEmail - userAddress: " + userAddress);
        console.log("serverCode - getUserInfoByEmail - userFullname: " + userFullname);

    }
}
```

The `null` checks do not return null, there are no errors.

Here is the output from the console:

```
Tue Nov 14 15:22:17 GMT-700 2017 clientCode - newValue: myemail@this.eml
Tue Nov 14 15:22:18 GMT-700 2017 serverCode - getUserInfoByEmail: myemail@this.eml
Tue Nov 14 15:22:18 GMT-700 2017 serverCode - getUserByEmail() - 1
Tue Nov 14 15:22:18 GMT-700 2017 serverCode - getUserByEmail() - user: 0
Tue Nov 14 15:22:18 GMT-700 2017 serverCode - getUserInfoByEmail - userPhone: undefined
Tue Nov 14 15:22:18 GMT-700 2017 serverCode - getUserInfoByEmail - userAddress: undefined
Tue Nov 14 15:22:18 GMT-700 2017 serverCode - getUserInfoByEmail - userFullname: undefined
```

Appreciate any direction and help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are two questions

> I am using the User Picker for Google App Maker and it only seems to return the email address.

If you want User Picker to provide you with Directory record, then you can check `valueIsRecord` checkbox. After that you'll be able to access Directory record through `widget.value`:

[image]

> code which returns undefined for the 3 values

You cannot iterate through `Array` using `for...in`([learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)) loop in javascript(this construction will give you keys, but not values). You can use `forEach`([learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) or old school `for` loop([learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)).

There is a third option: `for...of`([learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)), but it is not supported by App Script's javascript implementation.